# designing list with CSS

Tags: css, list, overflow, html-lists

i am looking for a way to prevent a **horizontal, inline unordered list** from breaking into seperate lines once contained inside a  element with specific width (shorter than the list). the  element has "overflow" set to "hidden".

the only way i found to create that effect is by giving a specific width to the "UL" element but now, i have to create that effect for a list with unknown width!! (user can add items to list). 
is there any other way? it would help me so much!!

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add "white-spacing: nowrap" to the UL? That might work out: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this piece of code to display list item

```
#list   {
        width:476px;
        height:40px;
        margin-top:40px;
        float:right;
    }

    #list ol    {
        padding:0;
        margin:10px 0px 0px 27px;
        float:left;
        display:inline;
    }

    #list li    {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        display:inline;
        float:left;
    }
```

Comment: for your requirement make width to the maximum you can present and make height auto.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ul.one-liner { white-space: nowrap; }
ul.one-liner li { display: inline }
```

Answer (score 0):

**[[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/iqira3/4/)]**

```
#container {
  width: 100px; /* container's specific width */
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden;  
}

ul { 
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none; 
  width: 10000px;
}

ul li { 
  display: inline;
}
```